# mpdf showing a radio button and checkbox selected

Tags: php, pdf, checkbox, mpdf

I have a quick question.

I creating an pdf output when the user clicks on the button. However the problem I'm having is the radio and checkbox. I tried to use the standard
    ($answer == 'What the value is' ) ? 'checked':''

however when it is outputted to a pdf, it doesn't show the radio button or checkbox selected. Is there way I can have the radio buttons or checkbox's selected in an pdf output?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution. What I did was I put the the checkbox and radio button in if statement and I did put the code in the following format:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked"> Yes
```

That did the trick..

Comment: <input type="radio" checked> wont work, should be <input type="radio" checked="checked">, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. You saved my time. In the same way Selected attribute should be `<select name="city"><option value="HYD" selected="selected">Display</option></selected>`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if ($answer = "1"){

 $output .= 'Yes <input type="checkbox" checked /> ';
}
else{
 $output .= 'Yes <input type="checkbox" /> ';
}
```

Where is 1 true. I assume that, you get these values from db. In this cycle check these values if it checked.

Comment: Yes that is correct it is coming from the db. I'll give it a shot.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" value="1" <?php $data->input_11 == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : null ?> > Yes

<input type="checkbox" value="1" <?php $data->input_11 == 1 ? 'checked="checked"' : null ?> > Yes
```

**Its Work for me**